# Union of CSS Radial Gradient vs Intersection

Tags: css, webkit, radial-gradients

I'm trying to get two radial gradients to render on the same DOM element but it seems like they're rendering the intersection of the two gradients rather than the union (which is what I want).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VUzLS/1/

To save you some time, if there is no overlap, it does not render both gradients, it will render nothing as there is no intersection.

Is there a way to make this render the union of the two gradients?

Edit: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1uek.png) should illustrate what I want. I would like the gradients defined by the red ellipses to take up the entirety of the white section but right now they're only taking up the intersection of the area defined by the red ellipses.

Comment: offtopic: there is new syntax for gradients.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty good overview of [css3 gradients](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-radial-gradient-syntax/)

I find the syntax pretty confusing and am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Here is an updated version of your example that shows multi-color radial gradients with an inner box shadow to show some other css3 drawing ideas. You can use rgba colors for transparency.

```
div {
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, 30px 40px, red 10%, orange 40%, yellow 65%, brown 190%);  
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -20px -20px 20px 20px orange, inset 20px 20px 20px 20px green;
  border-radius: 20%;
  }
```

perhaps you could draw a picture of what your after.

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/nlgCe.png) should illustrate what I want. I would like the gradients defined by the red ellipses to take up the entirety of the white section but right now they're only taking up the intersection of the area defined by the red ellipses.